# Корректное удаление файлов C#

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы, webbrowser

Написал такой метод для удаления файлов

```
public static void deleteFile(params string[] fileName)
{
    foreach (string f in fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(Properties.Settings.Default.diskString + f)) File.Delete(Properties.Settings.Default.diskString + f);
    }
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
HelpClass.deleteFile("poster.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", downloadFileName);
```

Вот эти файлы, перечисленные в аргументах метода, предварительно вставляются в поля сайта через webbrowser. Соответственно, при запуске метода файлы якобы удаляются, но на самом деле остаются до полного закрытия программы. Прикрепил скрин, как они на диске выглядят после этого. Если попытаться их открыть, то пишет, что отсутствует разрешение на доступ к расположению файла.
Если же в webbrowser их не вставлять, то все хорошо удаляется.
Пытался очищать память при закрытии второй формы (событие FormClosed), на которой находится webbrowser, двумя способами:

```
this.Dispose();
```

и

```
GG.Collect();
```

результата нет. Один раз сработал второй способ, но больше почему-то не работает))

Файлы в поля на сайте вставляются следующим образом:

```
Populate().ContinueWith((_) =>
        {

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

async Task PopulateInputFile_poster(HtmlElement file_poster)
{
    file_poster.Focus();
    dialog show up
    var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
        {
            SendKeys.Send(Properties.Settings.Default.diskString + "" + "poster.jpg" + "{ENTER}");
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    file_poster.InvokeMember("Click"); 

    await sendKeyTask;

    await Task.Delay(500);
}

async Task Populate()
{
    var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");


    //постер
    foreach (HtmlElement file_poster in elements)
    {
        if (file_poster.GetAttribute("name") == "screen")
        {
            file_poster.Focus();
            await PopulateInputFile_poster(file_poster);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разбирайтесь, кто держит дескриптор файлов после загрузки. Для этого можете воспользоваться Process Explorer'ом https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh а можете объяснить, как это сделать с помощью данной программы? Я только понял, что появились новые потоки после запуска второй формы. И они не исчезли после ее закрытия...

Comment: если ты открываешь поток для чтения файла - нужно его закрывать. Если ты открываешь файл с некими правами - нужно освободить это открытие. Где конкретно ты это сделал я не подскажу. Но советую почитать, например, про .Dispose() метод в IDisposable обьектов. 99% что ты где-то файлы открывал и банально не закрыл.

Comment: @Andrew в методах, где я скачиваю файлы, Везде прописан Dispose. Проверил. Да и обернуты все скачивания в using, т.е. они автоматически должны закрыться. Значит остается использование этих файлов при вставке в input в webbrowser. Код этого я привел в своем посте. Можете глянуть, надо ли там что-то закрывать?

Comment: Тогда странная ситуация. А метод deleteFile() вызывается когда?  Сразу после того как  как запустил аплоад? Или через некоторое время? Может он не успевает залить как ты пытаешся удалить

Comment: @Andrew вызывается по кнопке. Я жду секунды 2-3 после закрытия формы и нажимаю ее.

Comment: а что случается если ты залил файлы, а потом вручную пробуешь удалить эти файлы не закрывая своей программы?

Comment: @Andrew спокойно удаляются

Comment: А попробуй рефрешнуть папку после програмного удаления. Может быть так, что файлы удалены, но сам эксплоурер не обновил об этом данные.

Comment: @Andrew после нажатия на кнопку миниатюры файлов продолжают отображаться. После обновления непосредственно в папке файлы картинок становятся такими, как на скриншоте, который я прикрепил к стартовому посту

Comment: А точно файлы удаляются? Просто, если файл действительно держится вашей программой, то у вас должно вылететь исключение. Вы в дебаггере точно попадаете на место удаления файлов? А то может быть у вас условие неверное из-за неправильной конфигурации и все такое...

Comment: @iluxa1810 точно. Если не запускать вторую форму, то все указанные файлы удаляются с диска. А если запустить, потом закрыть ее, нажать на кнопку удаления, то они становятся, как на скрине. Если после этого еще раз нажать на кнопку, то уже тогда вылетает исключение (видимо, из-за отсутствия прав на доступ к файлам). Да и в поля webbrowser эти файлы вставляются, а значит путь указан правильно. Я сейчас даже специально проверил и указал прямые пути к файлам - результат тот же.

Comment: А поведение репродьюсится на другом инстансе железа/операционки?

Comment: @Andrew как минимум у меня поведение аналогичное. Файлы, которые поучаствовали в upload'е WebBrowser'а при удалении (не важно, программном или через проводник) оставляют непонятный файл, любой доступ к которому выдает ошибку. Перевод WebBrowser'а на другой документ, Dispose, GC.Collect и т.п. не решают проблему. После завершения процесса этот файл сам собой исчезает. Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашел похожую проблему вот [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/11b8194a-fd22-4a44-81b2-ae51ff705c45/webbrowser-control-is-locking-files-cant-delete-during-application-cleanup?forum=wpf)

Там говорится, что если перейти на произвольный адрес, например, http://localhost/ , то ресурсы освобождаются и могут быть удалены.

В этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495619/how-can-i-delete-the-file-that-has-been-navigated-in-a-webbrowser-control) так же сталкиваются с этой проблемой и предлагают такое же решение:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    Application.DoEvents();

File.Delete(fileName);
```

Если это не поможет, то можно подойти радикально, используя [`AppDomain`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=netframework-4.7.2):

1. Создаете класс наследник от `MarshalByRefObject`
2. Оборачиваете этот класс вокруг `webbrowser`
3. Создаете новый домен
4. В этом домене создаете объект вашего класса
5. Взаимодействуете с браузером через него
6. Когда хотите удалить файлы, выгружаете домен целиком

Как вариант, еще можно попробовать стороннюю библиотеку `CefSharp` . Она является альтернативой webbrowser на хромиуме.

Comment: Кинул на вторую форму кнопку, на которую прописал Ваш код, но результат тот же...

Comment: @АндрейФедоров, а зачем вы используете webbrowser? Чем легковесный WebClient не устраивает?

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Ну есть радикальный подход, вы можете работать в webbrowser в отдельном домене, а потом его выгружать перед удалением файлов.

Comment: а разве у webClient есть графический интерфейс? Мне необходимо наглядно видеть как заполнились те или иные поля на сайте, чтобы, в случае чего, отредактировать их. А можно поподробнее про отдельный домен?

Comment: А вы используется веббраузер для тестирования сайта?

Comment: нет, я использую его как часть программы, которая сама публикует материалы на сайт, заполняя нужные поля.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров ну тогда, попробуйте отдельный домен или CerfSharp. Еще есть Selenium.

Comment: Так а что вы подразумеваете под отдельный домен? Я немного не понимаю)

Comment: Яж ссылку оставил https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Что именно хоть помогло? Выгрузка домена или перешел на CerfSharp?

Comment: с доменом у меня чет не вышло, не настолько хорошо я пока в языке разбираюсь) Поэтому перешел на CerfSharp, ну и еще с awesomium, вроде бы, тоже все нормально. Только он оч большой, из-за чего размер приложения оч раздувается